# Компилятор не видит класс внутри класса

Tags: c#, namespace

Есть 2 класса в 2-х файлах:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Dig.FMD_;

public class LB : MonoBehaviour {
}
```

и

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dig.FMD_
{

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class LineRenderer_ : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public LB test;//< bug
    }
}
```

Компилятор ругается, пишет что в классе LineRenderer_:
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `LB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Почему LB не виден в LineRenderer_???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните `LB` в какой-нибудь `namespace`, можно тупо тот же `Dig.FMD_`, тогда ничего больше делать не придется - в ином случае в файле класса `LineRenderer_` (кстати, на кой ляд вам "_" в конце имен?) нужно прописать using этого нового неймспейса.

Comment: "кстати, на кой ляд вам "_" в конце имен?" - чтобы можно было писать типа: ClassName_1. Обертка в этот же namespace не помогла.

Comment: А using то прописали при этом?

Comment: Обернул так: namespace Dig.FMD_
{
    public class LB : MonoBehaviour {}
}

Comment: В принципе должно уже было увидеть. В чем-то у вас еще косяк. А файлы в одной сборке точно?

Comment: Должны быть в одной. У меня Unity, если не создавать namespace Dig.FMD_, то все работает. А если создавать, то какая-то пляска с бубном. Сейчас посмотрю что они говорят о сборках

Answer (score 0):

У Вас класс `LineRenderer_` объявлен в пространстве имен `Dig.FMD_`. Когда Вы в нем обращаетесь к идентификатору `LB`, который ищется в этом же пространстве имен и во всех пространствах, указанных в `using`

Но там его нет. `LB` у Вас определен в глобальном пространстве имен. Вот и ссылайтесь на глобальное пространство

```
public class LineRenderer_ : MonoBehaviour
{
    public global::LB test;
}
```

Comment: Сослался, пишет такие странные вещи: The type or namespace name `LB' could not be found in the global namespace. Are you missing an assembly reference? Он похоже совсем его не видит что ли???

Comment: Это не сильно поможет, так как компилятор и так шерстит глобальное пространство имен.